# Keeping the original behavior of a file input in Fine-Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader, phpfox

My problem is this: i have a form with a file input. This file input has a onchange event attached. How can i add Fineuploader to handle things like validation (fize size, format,), thumbnail previews, but not the upload of the files and keep the original behavior of the file input?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to use this for a template, created for a CMS. This cms has a lot of core modules that have upload forms (for these forms i'm using FineUploader at its whole power). But users can add other modules too, and these modules can contain upload forms too. I want uniformity in this theme and i want these upload forms to have the look and feel of those created fully with FineUploader.

Comment: Because i don't know what these 3d-party modules do, what events they have attached to the file inputs, how the form should be submitted etc., i want only for these forms to add just a few things from FineUploader that will not affect their behavior, but it will improve the UX, like validation, previews. Maybe there is a way to make FineUploader handle the upload too? Thanks. Am I looking correctly to this problem? Or should i consider doing other things?

Comment: I would try to see if you can integrate Fine Uploader into your existing CMS (which one is it, btw?). Including the upload functionality.

Comment: The CMS is PHPFox, it's more of a MVC framework to build your social network. And it's not that popular. From a developer look, their code is awful, but it works, and that's what the users want.

Comment: If you want to take advantage of many of Fine Uploader's features (chunking, progress, etc.) you're going to need to make sure your upload endpoint is set up the correct way. PHPFox's source is not open so I cannot see how their upload endpoint(s) work. One idea is to contribute your own. We have [PHP examples](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php).

Comment: Another theoretical idea is to turn `autoUpload` off in Fine Uploader. Use `addFiles` or `addBlobs` to add files to Fine Uploader from the input element's `onchange`, then use `drawThumbnail`, `validate`, etc. on Fine Uploader's files, but then have the actual file/form submission occur via the PHPFox addon form (i.e., Fine Uploader's upload button does nothing). FU's [API methods](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) and [Core Options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html) are going to be essential for this.

Comment: @MarkFeltner Please move this comment to an answer.  This is my suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of many of Fine Uploader's features (chunking, progress, etc.) you're going to need to make sure your upload endpoint is set up the correct way. PHPFox's source is not open so I cannot see how their upload endpoint(s) work. One idea is to contribute your own. We have [PHP examples](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php).

Another theoretical idea is to turn autoUpload off in Fine Uploader. Use addFiles or addBlobs to add files to Fine Uploader from the input element's onchange, then use drawThumbnail, validate, etc. on Fine Uploader's files, but then have the actual file/form submission occur via the PHPFox addon form (i.e., Fine Uploader's upload button does nothing). FU's [API](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) methods and [Core Options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html) are going to be essential for this.

Comment: I have a similar need - I want to be able to use drag-drop, previews and other UI-related functionality, without uploading. Any chance of a more complete example? @ray-nicholus

Comment: If you turn `autoUpload` off then you can programmatically get the file with Fine Uploader's API `getFile` and then you can do whatever you want.